# save matlab matrix in txt file with different precision in one column

Tags: matlab, precision

I have a large matrix in matlab (10000x20) and I want to save it through dlmwrite with different precision on some columns. 
I have to use

for ii = 1:size(m, 1)
fprintf(file, '%0.1f %0.2f\n', m(ii, 1), m(ii, 2));
end

for all columns or is there an easier way?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I cannot understand this ii = 1:size(m,1) part, what is m? you have 20 columns - what type are each/all of them? Double/Strings/Ints?

Comment: The way you do it is pretty much it. In case you transpose the matrix you will get rid of the Matlab loop though. Then `fprintf` will iterate the format specifier until it comes to the end of the matrix.